# NoReverseMatch at /blog/ in django 2.0

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

am getting this error trying to set a blog category page 
NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'category_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\/category\-detail\/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

Here is my url.py

```html
from django.urls import path,include
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/',views.post_list,name="post_list"),
    path('blog/post-detail/<slug:slug>',views.post_detail,name="post_detail"),
    path('blog/category-detail/<slug:slug>',views.category_detail,name="category_detail"),

]
```

views.py

```html
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from.models import Post,Category

# Create your views here.
def post_list(request):
    object_list=Post.objects.all()
    context={
        'object_list': object_list,
    }
    return render(request,"blog.html",context)

def post_detail(request,slug=None):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post,slug=slug)
    context={
       'post':post,
    }
    return render(request,"post_detail.html",context)

def category_detail(request,slug=None):
    category=get_object_or_404(Category,slug=slug)
    post=Post.objects.filter(category=category,status='Published')
    context={
        'category':category,
        'post':post,
    }
    return render(request,"category_detail.html",context)
```

blog.html

```html
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {% if obj.status == 'Published' %}
      <article>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <img src="images/blog1.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
        <div class="post-content">

    <h2>{{obj.title}}</h2>

    <div>
    {{obj.created}}  Author {{obj.user}} <h4><a href="{% url 'category_detail' slug=post.category.slug %}">{{obj.Category}}</a></h4>
    <hr/>
    <p>{{obj.body}}</p>
    <a class="mtr-btn button-navy ripple" href= "{% url 'post_detail' obj.slug %}">Continue reading →</a><br>
    </div>
    </article>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

category_detail.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block seo_title %}{{category.seo_title}}{% endblock %}
{% block seo_description %}{{category.seo_description}}{% endblock %}
{% block Content %}
<h2>{{category.title}}</h2>
<p>{{category.description}}</p>
{% for item in post %}
{{item.title}}
{{item.body|truncatechars:50}}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock Content %}
```

NOTE THE OTHER VIEWS.PY ARE WORKING FINE JUST THE category_detail function

Comment: As you are referencing obj you should change your url to `{% url 'category-detail' obj.category.slug %}`

Answer (score 0):

As the error said, the argument is missing here. Maybe you need to change `{% url 'category_detail' slug=post.Category.slug %}` with `{% url 'category_detail' slug=obj.category.slug %}` because I do not see any `post` variable reference in the `blog.html` template.

#### update

You have not shared your Model codes, but I am assuming your `Post` Model has Foreign Key to `Category` Model and it looks like `Category=models.ForeignKey(Category)`. So you need to update the view like this:

```
def category_detail(request,slug=None):
    category=get_object_or_404(Category,slug=slug)
    post=Post.objects.filter(Category=category,status='Published')
```

Comment: Thanks worked but going to url http://localhost:8000/blog/category-detail/slug  gives an error FieldError at /blog/category-detail/python
 Cannot resolve keyword 'category' into field. Choices are: Category, Category_id, body, created, id, seo_description, seo_title, slug, status, title, updated, user, user_id